# Course schedule - Topological sort

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, depth-first-search, topological-sort

**Problem statement:**

There are a total of numCourses courses you have to take, labeled from 0 to numCourses - 1. You are given an array prerequisites where prerequisites[i] = [ai, bi] indicates that you must take course bi first if you want to take course ai.

For example, the pair [0, 1], indicates that to take course 0 you have to first take course 1.
Return true if you can finish all courses. Otherwise, return false.

**Implementation:**

This problem uses the concept of topological sort. So, I am trying to implement it using Stack and DFS as per this concept but getting index out of range: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting/. Below is my code.

```
public class Solution {
    Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
    bool[] visited = null;
    public bool CanFinish(int numCourses, int[][] prerequisites) {
        visited = new bool[numCourses];
        
        for(int i = 0; i < numCourses; i++){
            if(visited[i] == false)
                DFS(i, prerequisites);
        }
        return numCourses == stack.Count;
    }
    
    private void DFS(int course, int[][] prerequisites){
        visited[course] = true; // index out of bounds exception here
        
        for(int i = 0; i < prerequisites[course].Length; i++)
            if(!visited[prerequisites[course][i]])
                DFS(prerequisites[course][i], prerequisites);
        
        stack.Push(course);
    }
}
```

**Test-1:**

2

[[1,0]]

Result: failed with index out of bounds exception

**Test-2:**

2

[[1,0],[0,1]]

Result: Output is true but expected is false

There are other implementations (using BFS, queue) but I wanted to know if we can implement using DFS and stack. I do have a working solution but need some help my code implementation and if someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please add debug-information, a small failing example and more details where exactly the error occurs.

Comment: @MrSmith42 added more details

Comment: every time you call `CanFinish` it overwrites `visited`, is this intended? Don't you loose the already visited courses? I also think you might overcomplicate your actual use case. It would be much easier if you check if the "student" has already finished all courses that are prerequisites. I don't see why you need any sort algorthim at all.

Comment: @Mat I think the question is more about "Is there any course that's impossible to take ?" than "Can X student take Y course given he has Z1,Z2,Z3 visited courses ?"

Comment: This is problem is based on Graph data structure and the underlying concept is to detect if it has a cycle, hence the use of topological sort.

Comment: test 1 fails because you want to verify 2 courses but you only give prerequisites for 1 course 
IS [[1,0]] 
SHOULD BE [[1,0],[]]

Comment: test 2 fails because of missing cycle detection. hint `DFS` should return bool.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from the prerequisites data and how you use it :
The prerequisites are array of 2 numbers, the first being the course you want to take, the second one of its prerequisites.

```
private void DFS(int course, int[][] prerequisites){
    visited[course] = true; // index out of bounds exception here
    
    for(int i = 0; i < prerequisites[course].Length; i++)
        if(!visited[prerequisites[course][i]])
            DFS(prerequisites[course][i], prerequisites);
    
    stack.Push(course);
}
```

In this function, you call `prerequisite[course].Length`, expecting it to give you all prerequisite of the course, but you'll get a random prerequisite.
What you need to do is :

```
private void DFS(int course, int[][] prerequisites){
    visited[course] = true; // index out of bounds exception here
    
    for(int i = 0; i < prerequisites.Length; i++) // Check all prerequisites
        if(prerequisites[i][0] == course && !visited(prerequisite[i][1]){ 
        // If this is a prerequisite for target course 
        // and we haven't visited the requisited course
            DFS(prerequisites[i][1], prerequisites); // We visit the prerequisite course
        }
    stack.Push(course);
}
```